# Ext js front-end project as a module - how start?

Tags: extjs

In the future I will create a only front-end project of Ext JS 6. This project must be created like a module (something like plugin), because this project could be integrated with anothers projects in Sencha. What is the best solution for start with this conception? Thanks

Comment: Sencha has so-called packages that you can include in your projects. You can make your own package.

Comment: And that's enough?

Comment: Sencha has some documentation about packages, which you should read first, e.g.: https://www.sencha.com/blog/understanding-sencha-cmd-packages/ If you have read it, I will try to answer specialized questions that are left open.

Comment: Hey, I have a question. I created packages and I created app, but I'm not sure that I did it in correct way. By using app like a module, app should be in path workspace/packages/local/../ ? In this path I have directories like build, examples, resources, src, so I'm thinking that my app should be in this directory, not in directly ../workspace/myapp true?